# Is it true that $A \otimes_{\Bbb Z} B= A \otimes _{ R} B$ for every commutative ring $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

I have been obtaining a weird statement:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring $A,B$ both $R$-modules. Then $A \otimes_{\Bbb Z} B= A \otimes _{ R} B$  as abelian groups.

Proof: We may regard $A \otimes _{\Bbb Z} B$ as an $R$-module by acting $r(a \otimes b) = ra \otimes b$. There is thus an $R$-billinear map inducing $$A \otimes _R B \rightarrow A \otimes B$$ where $ a \otimes b \mapsto a \otimes b$. Conversely, there is also a billiner map inducing  $$A \otimes B \rightarrow A \otimes _R B$$
where $a \otimes b \mapsto a \otimes b$.  They form inverse to one another.

---

What has gone wrong in the proof?

---

EDIT: I believe I have found my main problem. So I took the $R$-module structure for $A \otimes B$ to be that induced from the map 
$$ R \times A \otimes B \rightarrow A \otimes B, (r,a \otimes b) \mapsto ra \otimes b $$ 
But this does not imply $ra \otimes b = a \otimes rb $. Which is required to induce the map $$A \otimes _R B \rightarrow A \otimes B $$

---

This is seen in the example given by egreg, that with $\Bbb Z$ given the induced qutoient structure of $R= \Bbb Z[x]$, in $\Bbb Z \otimes _{\Bbb Z} R \cong \Bbb Z^{(N)}$
$$ 0 = x 1 \otimes 1 \not= 1 \otimes x $$ 
Since under the isomorphism, the latter item is $(1) $ in the 1st level of $\Bbb Z^{(N)}$.

Comment: You never defined the inverse. And that's what's missing.

Comment: "Conversely, there is also a bilinear map inducing..." You never define that map in the post.

Comment: The problem with that map, as illustrated by egreg's answer, is it is not well defined.

Comment: Which I am still confused, why is it not well defined? There is a bilinear map $A \times B \rightarrow A \otimes _R B$, $(a,b) \mapsto a \otimes b$, then we use Universal Property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing too many steps implicitly.

In your second step, you want to say that the natural map $A\times B \to A \otimes_R B$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear.  That's true, and so it gives a map $A\otimes_\mathbb{Z} B \to A\otimes_R B$.

In your first step, you want to say that the natural map $A\times B \to A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B$ is $R$-bilinear.  That's false; you've defined $r(a \otimes b) = ra\otimes b$, but that might not equal $a\otimes rb$.  So there's no universal property to apply that gives us a map $A\otimes_R B \to A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B$.

Comment: Thanks Slade. But why do we not have an $R$-module structure on $A \otimes _{\Bbb Z} B$? It goes as follows: There is a well defined map $$\tau_r: A \otimes B \rightarrow A \otimes B$$ $(a \otimes b) \mapsto ra \otimes b$. Thus, there is a well defined map $$R \times A \otimes B \mapsto A \otimes B$$ $(r, a \otimes b) \mapsto \tau_r(a \otimes b)$. This map gives an $R$-module structure on $A \otimes B$. Doesn't this make the map described $R$-bilinear giving $A \otimes _R B \rightarrow A \otimes B$?

Comment: You're right, my answer was a little unclear.  The point is that if you define $r(a \otimes b) = ra\otimes b$, you still need to prove that this equals $a\otimes rb$ for your map to be $R$-bilinear.

Comment: Thanks Slade, in fact, I have noticed the exact same thing (which I have updated in my post).

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true in general.

Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. If $A$ is any $R$-module, then
$$
A\otimes_R R\cong A
$$
but
$$
A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}R\cong A^{(\mathbb{N})}
$$
(direct sum of a countable number of copies of $A$). Now take $A=\mathbb{Z}$, which is an $R$-module because it is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)$.