# Exact sequence of sheaves on nilpotent thickening

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness, deformation-theory

I am rather confused by this argument in a lecture in MSRI's deformation theory case. It is Problem 1 and Remark 2.1  in page 17 notes of the [notes.](https://stacky.net/files/written/defthy07/defthy07.pdf) It is rather long

---

Here $R[I]$ is a square zero extension of $R$ by an $R$-module $I$.

[image]

---

Question

- How does one obtain the exact sequence of sheaves?  (-line 3)
- Where is flatness used? (-line 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see why you're confused: there's a small mistake here! It looks like these notes were written by Anton Geraschenko, given the notation and the webpage. It isn't mentioned in these notes, but in [these](https://stacky.net/files/written/Stacks/Stacks.pdf) you can see that something marked with $\star\star\star$ is something that the author didn't understand (explained on page 4).

The exact sequence of sheaves comes from the closed immersion $i : X\to X_C$ (which is a closed immersion as it is the base change of the closed immersion $\operatorname{Spec}R\to\operatorname{Spec}R[I]$). So, $i$ gives a surjection
$$
i^\sharp : \mathcal{O}_{X_C}\to i_\ast\mathcal{O}_X
$$
of sheaves. However, since $i$ is a homeomorphism we may identify the underlying topological spaces of $X_C$ and $X,$ and under this identification $i_\ast\mathcal{O}_X$ is simply $\mathcal{O}_X.$ Thus, we have a short exact sequence of sheaves
$$
0\to\mathcal{I}\to\mathcal{O}_{X_C}\to \mathcal{O}_X\to 0,
$$
and we simply need to identify the kernel $\mathcal{I}.$

Suppose for simplicity that $X_C = \operatorname{Spec}C'$ is affine. Then the exact sequence above is obtained from the exact sequence
$$
0\to I\to R[I]\to R\to 0
$$
by base changing to $C':$
$$
0\to I\otimes_{R[I]}C'\to R[I]\otimes_{R[I]}C'\to R\otimes_{R[I]} C'\to 0.
$$
This is still exact because $R[I]\to C'$ is flat -- this is where flatness is used! (The global analogue of this exact sequence is
$$
0\to I\otimes_C\mathcal{O}_{X_C}\to \mathcal{O}_{X_C}\to\mathcal{O}_X\to 0.)
$$

The question remains, why can we identify $I\otimes_C\mathcal{O}_{X_C}$ with $I\otimes_R\mathcal{O}_X$? In our affine case, the former corresponds to $I\otimes_{R[I]} C'$ and the latter corresponds to $I\otimes_R (R[I]\otimes_{R[I]}C') = I\otimes_R C'.$ There is a canonical map
$$
I\otimes_{R[I]} C'\to I\otimes_R C'
$$
and [as you already know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016990/what-are-the-commutative-rings-r-for-which-a-otimes-bbb-z-b-a-otimes), this map is an isomorphism when $R[I]\to R$ is an epimorphism. The map $R[I]\to R$ is a surjection, so it is certainly an epimorphism!