# Let $M$ be an $R$-module. If $N$ is an $R_P$ module then $M \otimes_R N \cong M\otimes_{R_P} N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $P$ be a maximal ideal of $R$.

I'm stuck in showing that **if $M$ is an $R$-module and $N$ is an $R_P$ module then $M \otimes_R N \cong M\otimes_{R_P} N$.**

How are we tensoring over $R_P$ if $M$ is not given as an $R_P$-module?

I've tried using the fact if $N$ is an $R_P$-module, then $N \cong N_P$.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, as stated, this doesn't make sense. To see that this doesn't work, suppose $R = \Bbb{Z},$ $P = (2),$ and $M = \Bbb{Z}/(3).$ Then $M$ is not a $\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}$-module, as $3\in\Bbb{Z}\setminus P$ does not act invertibly on $M.$ In order to make it a $\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}$-module, we need to localize at $(2).$ Doing so gives
$$M_{(2)} \cong \Bbb{Z}/(3)\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}\cong\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}/(3)\cong 0.$$

There are two natural ways to remedy this. We may either suppose that both $M$ and $N$ are $R_P$-modules to begin with, or we may form the natural $R_P$-module associated to $M,$ which is $M_P.$ Thus, statement here should be either:

- If $M$ and $N$ are $R_P$-modules, then the canonical map $M\otimes_R N\to M\otimes_{R_P}N$ is an isomorphism, or
- If $M$ is an $R$-module, and $N$ is an $R_P$-module, then $M\otimes_R N\cong M_P\otimes_{R_P}N.$

To prove the first statement above, use the fact that a localization is a ring epimorphism and the fact that if $R\to S$ is a ring epimorphism and $M,N$ are $S$-modules, then the canonical map $M\otimes_R N\to M\otimes_S N$ is an isomorphism (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016990/what-are-the-commutative-rings-r-for-which-a-otimes-bbb-z-b-a-otimes)).

To prove the second statement, we compute
\begin{align*}
M\otimes_R N&\cong M\otimes_R (R_P\otimes_{R_P} N)\\
&\cong (M\otimes_R R_P)\otimes_{R_P} N\\
&\cong M_P\otimes_{R_P} N.
\end{align*}